# mysql optimize data content: multi column or simple column hash data

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, hashtable

I actually have a table with 30 columns. In one day this table can get around 3000 new records!

The columns datas look like :

```
IMG                                        Name          Phone        etc..

http://www.site.com/images/image.jpg       John Smith    123456789    etc..
http://www.site.com/images/image.jpg       Smith John    987654321    etc..
```

I'm looking a way to optimize the size of the table but also the response time of the sql queries. I was thinking of doing something like :

```
Column1

http://www.site.com/images/image.jpg|John Smith|123456789|etc..
```

And then via php i would store each value into an array..

Would it be faster ?

**Edit**

So to take an example of the structure, let's say i have two tables :

```
package
package_content
```

Here is the structure of the table `package` :

```
id | user_id | package_name | date
```

Here is the structure of the table `package_content` :

```
id | package_id | content_name | content_description | content_price | content_color | etc.. > 30columns
```

The thing is for each package i can get up to 16rows of content. For example :

```
id   | user_id | package_name | date
260    11        Package 260    2013-7-30 10:05:00

 id | package_id | content_name | content_description | content_price | content_color | etc.. > 30columns
1     260          Content 1      Content 1 desc        58              white           etc..
2     260          Content 2      Content 2 desc        75              black           etc..
3     260          Content 3      Content 3 desc        32              blue            etc..
etc...
```

Then with php i make like that

```
select * from package
while not EOF {
   show package name, date etc..
   select * from package_content where package_content.package_id = package.id and package.id = package_id
   while not EOF{
       show package_content name, desc, price, color etc...
   }
}
```

Comment: Why does your table have 30 columns? Sounds like you could probably use [some normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  Also, don't put everything in one column on the table. What happens when you have to update someone's phone number? First, you have to load all your rows in the database to PHP, then you have to loop over all objects, trying to find the particular record that needs to be updated, then reload. vs `UPDATE table SET phone={new phone #} WHERE phone={old phone #}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Would it be faster?* Definitely not. If you needed to search by `Name` or `Phone` or `etc...` you'd have to pull those values out of `Column1` every time. You'd never be able to optimize those queries, ever.

If you want to make the table smaller it's best to look at splitting some columns off into another table. If you'd like to pursue that option, post the entire structure. But note that the number of columns doesn't affect speed *that* much. I mean it can, but it's way down on the list of things that will slow you down.

Finally, 3,000 rows per day is about 1 million rows per year. If the database is tolerably well designed, MySQL can handle this easily.

---

**Addendum**: partial table structures plus sample query and pseudocode added to question.

The pseudocode shows the `package` table being queried all at once, then matching `package_content` rows being queried one at a time. This is a very slow way to go about things; better to use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  package.id,
  user_id,
  package_name,
  date,
  package_content.*
FROM package
INNER JOIN package_content on package.id = package_content.id
WHERE whatever
ORDER BY whatever
```

That will speed things up right away.

If you're displaying on a web page, be sure to limit results with a `WHERE` clause - nobody will want to see 1,000 or 3,000 or 1,000,000 packages on a single web page :)

Finally, as I mentioned before, the number of columns isn't a huge worry for query optimization, but...

1. Having a really wide result row means more data has to go across the wire from MySQL to PHP, and
2. It isn't likely you'll be able to display 30+ columns of information on a web page without it looking terrible, especially if you're reading lots of rows.

With that in mind, you'll be better of picking specific `package_content` columns in your query instead of picking them all with a `SELECT *`.

Comment: Hi Gibbs, thank you for the answer. I don't need to select any specific columns in my php code, i usually select *. I edited my initial post and posted and example of the structure of the table so you can understand a bit how i structured my datas. Also i already optimized the column type (like not use varchar 255 when it's not needed)

Comment: Hi Yves - I've added some more information to my answer. You can speed things up a lot by using a single query instead of the multiple queries in your pseudocode, and I'd also recommend you decide exactly which columns you need and select only those rather than a `SELECT *`. Even if you `SELECT *` it's still not going to be the difference between super slow and super fast, but if you're not going to use certain columns there's no reason to include them in the query.

Comment: Thanks. Ok i will use a JOIN so i get only 1 query. Yes i also use a LIMIT displaying 30 results per page. I have to use all the column (most of them are used to be displayed in a jquery tooltip), but sometimes some of the columns are empty.. Like some content could have content_color to NULL. I don't know if i could make something about not selecting empty columns...

Comment: Excellent - I'm relieved you're using `LIMIT`; that will keep the result set nice and small. If you're using most of the columns then the `SELECT *` is fine; I just wanted to be sure you *really* need it and it looks like you do. As for the null/empty columns, they won't slow you down so don't worry about them. Overall it looks like you're headed in the right direction here. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much Gibbs. One more thing : Some of my contents get only few columns (only 4 to be exact). Would it be faster to move this content to a new table (for ie: 1 table with lots of content and an other one with smallest content) and then select the 3 tables (package, package_full_content, package_small_content) in 1 query?

Comment: Are the 4 columns also used by the packages that have lots of contents? If so, you're better off with something like `package`, `package_base_content` (for the 4 columns), and `package_extended_content` (for the extra columns). But if some packages use 4 columns and some use 7 and some use 12 and some use 20 - you get the idea - then splitting things up like this will be confusing and you're better off staying with the 30 columns.

Comment: Yes the 4 columns are used by both of the package content. So you're saying that it's faster selecting 3 tables(package_base_content = 4 columns and package_extended_content = 26columns) versus 2 tables (package_content = 30 columns) ?

Comment: Faster if you're getting 4 and slower if you're getting all 30, but not by much. Don't split them for speed purposes. The point is this: if the 26 columns apply to only a subset of the `package_content` items, that may mean they're "different", and if they're "different" then design principles say they should go into a different table. But a design review is something I'm afraid I can't help with - it's best done in a face-to-face meeting with data diagrams and formal requirements. To do it via messaging or chat would take hours.

Comment: ok i understand, i'll stay like this then! Thanks again for your time and i wish you a nice day or evening depending where you live ^^

Answer (score 1):

Don't combine any columns, this is no use and might even be slower in the end.

You should use indexes on a column where you query at. I do have a website with about 30 columns where atm are around 600.000 results. If you use `EXPLAIN` before a query, you should see if it uses any indexes. If you got a JOIN with 2 values and a WHERE at the same table. You should make a combined index with the 3 columns, in order from JOIN -> WHERE. If you join on the same table, you should see this as a seperate index.

For example:

```
SELECT p.name, p.id, c.name, c2.name 
FROM product p
JOIN category c ON p.cat_id=c.id
JOIN category c2 ON c.parent_id=c2.id AND name='Niels'
WHERE p.filterX='blaat'
```

You should have an combined index at category

```
parent_id,name
AND
id (probably the AI)
```

A index on product

```
cat_id
filterX
```

With this easy solution you can optimize queries from NOT DOABLE to 0.10 seconds, or even faster.

If you use MySQL 5.6 you should step over to INNODB because MySQL is better with optimizing JOINS and sub queries. Also MySQL will try to run them into MEMORY which will make it a lot faster aswel. Please keep in mind that backupping INNODB tables might need some extra attention.

You might also think about making MEMORY tables for super fast querieing (you do still need indexes).

You can also optimize by making integers size 4 (4 bytes, not 11 characters). And not always using VARCHAR 255.

Comment: HI Niels, thank you for answering. I don't really understand what index are for (I posted the structure if you could explain me how i could uses the index on that?) I will seek about innodb as you recommend it. My web server has 4gb of ram is that enough you think ? And yes i already optimized the columns type size. Thanks in advance!

Comment: MySQL has mutliple files (1 index file and the rest table files). It will first use the index file to find his results and doesn't need to open the complete data file. More information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimization-indexes.html I see you ar using a query in a for loop, please try to avoid that ! that's never wanted and will really slow your website.

Comment: Yes i already changed my query as Gibbs pointed it. I will follow your link and make some research about it. Thanks for your time.